# ¿Cómo hacer para que una frase no se corte, fracture o divida en CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Supongamos que tenemos que mantener sí o sí juntas unas frases, ya sea porque son importantes para el marketing o por que es el nombre de la marca.

¿Cómo haría para que estas frases no se corten al momento de ajustarse a diferentes resoluciones?

En este caso las frases (no palabras) son:

> The Burguer Cangreburguer (marca)
>
> Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer (producto)

O sea, cuando se ajusta a diferentes resoluciones a veces se ve como:

> The Burguer
>   Cangreburguer
>
> Cardiac Arrest
>   Hamburguer

Deberían ir juntas porque es, por ejemplo, el nombre de la marca y el producto.

Este es un pequeño ejemplo:

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <span class="brand">The Burguer Cangreburguer</span>, adipisicing elit. Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis at quae velit <span class="product">Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la frase que se corta?, cuando dices que se corta ¿es que se salta al segundo renglón, se sale de su contenedor no se ve?

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz, efectivamente es como dices se salta al segundo renglón o sea el nombre de The Burguer Cangreburguer que deberia mantenerse junto queda algo asi:
The Burguer  (salto de linea) Cangreburguer

Answer (score 5):

Lo que necesitas es hacer uso de los espacios en blanco que no pueden romperse ([`&nbsp;`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_duro)):

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <span class="brand">
        The&nbsp;Burguer&nbsp;Cangreburguer</span>, adipisicing elit.
        Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam
        repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis
        at quae velit <span class="product">
        Cardiac&nbsp;Arrest&nbsp;Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Si no deseas cambiar los espacios en blanco por entidades HTML `&nbsp;` durante la redacción del documento, puedes hacer uso del atributo [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Impedimos que el contenido pueda dividirse en los espacios en blanco */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <span class="brand">
        The Burguer Cangreburguer</span>, adipisicing elit.
        Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam
        repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis
        at quae velit <span class="product">
        Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Diferencias entre mi respuesta y la proporcionada por [@JorgeGuz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/150611/jorgeguz):

En caso de que el contenedor padre tenga un ancho inferior al ancho de la frase completa, en mi caso puede forzar al padre a tener un ancho mínimo que permita mantener todo en la misma línea o bien generar un scroll para poder visualizar lo que se desborda:

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* Impedimos que el contenido pueda dividirse en los espacios en blanco */
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.container {
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* Para generar scroll cuando no quepa el contenido */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, (<span class="brand">The
        Burguer Cangreburguer</span>), y a adipisicing elit.
        Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam
        repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis
        at quae velit <span class="product">
        Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Sin embargo con su solución el contenido del bloque puede finalmente dividirse en caso de que el ancho del padre sea inferior al ancho de la frase, produciéndose un comportamiento de bloque en la división de líneas (que he podido representar mejor poniendo entre paréntesis el texto):

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.container {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, (<span class="brand">The
        Burguer Cangreburguer</span>), y a adipisicing elit.
        Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam
        repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis
        at quae velit <span class="product">
        Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

La segunda opción que te ofrece [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) es muy buena, creo que con eso ya no tendrás ningún problema. Por aportar una tercera opción, puedes añadir a la clase que da el color al texto que te interesa mantener en una línea un `display: inline-block`. Con ello también te garantizas que permanezca unido el texto:

```css
.brand, .product {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, <span class="brand">
        The Burguer Cangreburguer</span>, adipisicing elit.
        Animi fugiat aperiam reprehenderit ad? Omnis quibusdam quam
        repellendus nisi totam, quaerat illo perferendis quas corporis
        at quae velit <span class="product">
        Cardiac Arrest Hamburguer</span> consectetur fugiat eaque.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Visualmente tu respuesta parece correcta, pero estás efectivamente pasando el texto a una nueva línea, separándola de su entorno. Fíjate en cómo la coma que va tras **The Burguer Cangreburguer** ha pasado a la siguiente línea en vez de mantenerse junto al texto. Si cambias el ancho de `200px` a `300px` en tu respuesta y en la mía podrás apreciar mejor la diferencia. Si editas tu respuesta y cambias `block` por `inline-block` te ganas mi +1 :)

Comment: tienes toda la razón! :)

Comment: Ya tienes mi +1. Como diferencia entre tu respuesta y la mía, en caso de tener un ancho de contenedor inferior al contenido del texto, mi método fuerza al contenido a mantener el texto completo en una única línea y en tu caso las palabras terminan por dividirse en líneas diferentes, una única a la vista del padre. Dependiendo del comportamiento que le interese más al OP tu solución podría presentarle una mejor alternativa que la mía. He editado mi respuesta para agregar la diferencia entre ambas soluciones :)

Answer (score 2):

Si comprendo bien, lo que no quieres es que el texto pase el `<div>`. Bien, aquí dejo un ejemplo para lograr eso con unas letras sin espacios:

```css
.texto {
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="texto">
asdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasdklfsfsdasd
</div>
```

Lo que uso es [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) y también se puede usar [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap).

Lo que hace la propiedad `word-wrap` es permitir que la palabra continúe y se ajuste al tamaño del `<div>` o lo que tu vayas a usar que contenga texto al igual que `overflow-wrap: break-word;`.

Comment: Por desgracia lo que desea es justo lo contrario, mantener juntas las palabras.